# sql server 2012 : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I receive this error and I cant find out why.

```
case when FormFields.fieldtype like '%date%'        
    then 'not' + fieldname + ' is null and ( convert(datetime,' 
         + fieldname +',103)  < ' 
         + coalesce(str(FormFields.MinDate),'1/1/1900') + ')' 
         + ' or ( convert(datetime,' + fieldname +',103) > ' 
         + coalesce(str(FormFields.MaxDate), '1/1/2200') + ')' 
         +
else     
         'not '+ fieldname + ' is null and ( convert(float,'+ fieldname+') <'
         + coalesce(str(FormFields.MinValue),'-99999999') 
         + ' or convert(float,'+ fieldname+') >' 
         + coalesce(str(FormFields.MaxValue),'99999999') +')' 
         +
end
```

previous code without any error:

```
'not '+ fieldname + ' is null and ( convert(float,'+ fieldname+') <'
     + coalesce(str(FormFields.MinValue),'-99999999') 
     + ' or convert(float,'+ fieldname+') >' 
     + coalesce(str(FormFields.MaxValue),'99999999') +')' 
     +
```

I just wanted to add another case

Comment: Perhaps the superflous + sign at the end of your `then` line?

Comment: There's another one before the end

Comment: its part of a building string code that's why there are extra '+'s

Comment: The '+' should go after the 'END'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 extra `+` in your query, 1 in the end of the `THEN` part, another in end of the  `ELSE` part. If you need to combine `CASE` expression with another string, use `+` after `END`. Try in following:

```
case when FormFields.fieldtype like '%date%'        
    then 'not' + fieldname + ' is null and ( convert(datetime,' 
         + fieldname +',103)  < ' 
         + coalesce(str(FormFields.MinDate),'1/1/1900') + ')' 
         + ' or ( convert(datetime,' + fieldname +',103) > ' 
         + coalesce(str(FormFields.MaxDate), '1/1/2200') + ')' 

else     
         'not '+ fieldname + ' is null and ( convert(float,'+ fieldname+') <'
         + coalesce(str(FormFields.MinValue),'-99999999') 
         + ' or convert(float,'+ fieldname+') >' 
         + coalesce(str(FormFields.MaxValue),'99999999') +')' 

end 
+ 'Any string after CASE expression'
```

Comment: problem solved but now I receive "Invalid column name 'MinDate'." and "Invalid column name 'MaxDate'."

Comment: @aggicd so that's mean you have provided incorrect column names, as in your correct query, you're using only `MinValue` and `MaxValue`, maybe there is no `MinDate` and `MaxDate` at all?

Comment: there are, but they are datetime columns

Comment: This is another question and there nobody can help you without full query.